# Programmatically loading clojure libraries

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to programmatically load some clojure libraries to make a simple auto-test program.

What I end up sending to require is this

```
(require :reload '("peg" "test.peg-test"))
```

How do I transform that list into something useful, or am I totally barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you aware that there are testing libraries available in clojure.contrib?

You may find it easier to do this if you orient your thinking around [namespaces](http://www.clojure.org/namespaces). If you look at Bill Clementson's [user.clj](http://bc.tech.coop/blog/docs/user.clj) you will find a useful function for clearing out the `user` namespace and reloading the base namespaces in preparation for bringing in your testing namespaces.

In any case, using namespaces your code would work like this:

```
(ns testing-peg
  (:require [peg test.peg-test])
```

Comment: the user.clj seems to have what I want.  The other missing piece, taking a string and then using it when calling require, is done with a call to (symbol name).  (map #(ns-reload! (symbol %)) '("peg" "test.peg-test"))

Comment: Ok, good. I wasn't 100% sure the problem was, so I tried to touch on all the possible ones. user.clj was the first idea, and the other two paragraphs came later. Mark up another one for the value of gut responses!